# Fast, small, and repetitive matrix multiplication in Python

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, cython, scientific-computing

I'm looking for a way to very quickly multiply together many 4x4 matrices using Python/Cython/Numpy, can anyone give any suggestions?

To show my current attempt, I have an algorithm which needs to compute

```
A_1 * A_2 * A_3 * ... * A_N
```

where every

```
A_i != A_j
```

An example of it in Python:

```
means = array([0.0, 0.0, 34.28, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4])
stds = array([ 4.839339, 4.839339, 4.092728, 0.141421, 0.141421, 0.141421])

def fn():
    steps = means+stds*numpy.random.normal(size=(60,6))
    A = identity(4)
    for step in steps:
        A = dot(A, transform_step_to_4by4(step))
%timeit fn()

1000 loops, best of 3: 570 us per loop
```

Implementing this algorithm in Cython/Numpy is approximately 100x slower than the equivalent code using Eigen/C++ with all optimizations. I really don't want to use C++, though.

Comment: Code a plugin in C? Python has a pretty easy C API.

Comment: What's this supposed to do? `transform_step_to_4by4(step)`

Comment: @askewchan, suffice to say it's a coordinate transformation from a 6D vector to a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: @Mike If you can apply it to all the arrays in a list, then you can use reduce as in my answer and it should speed things up.

Comment: Optimizing a loop where you don't know what happens in the innermost iteration is a poking in the dark. What does `transform_step_to_4by4` do? "suffice to say" is not enough, unless you at least say if it can be vectorized itself.

Answer (score 6):

If you are having to make a Python function call to produce each of the matrices you want to multiply, then you are basically screwed performance-wise. But  if you can vectorize the `transform_step_to_4by4` function, and have it return an array with shape `(n, 4, 4)` then you can save some time using `matrix_multiply`:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.umath_tests import matrix_multiply

matrices = np.random.rand(64, 4, 4) - 0.5

def mat_loop_reduce(m):
    ret = m[0]
    for x in m[1:]:
        ret = np.dot(ret, x)
    return ret

def mat_reduce(m):
    while len(m) % 2 == 0:
        m = matrix_multiply(m[::2], m[1::2])
    return mat_loop_reduce(m)

In [2]: %timeit mat_reduce(matrices)
1000 loops, best of 3: 287 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit mat_loop_reduce(matrices)
1000 loops, best of 3: 721 us per loop

In [4]: np.allclose(mat_loop_reduce(matrices), mat_reduce(matrices))
Out[4]: True
```

You now have log(n) Python calls instead of n, good for a 2.5x speed-up, which will get close to 10x for n = 1024. Apparently `matrix_multiply` is a ufunc, and as such has a `.reduce` method, which would allow your code to run no loops in Python. I have not been able to make it run though, keep getting an arcane error:

```
In [7]: matrix_multiply.reduce(matrices)
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Reduction not defined on ufunc with signature
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't compare the speed to your method since I don't know how you turn your `(60,6)` array into a `(4,4)`, but this works to take the dot of a sequence:

```
A = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
B = np.arange(4,20).reshape(4,4)
C = np.arange(8,24).reshape(4,4)

arrs = [A, B, C]

P = reduce(np.dot, arrs)
```

And this is equivalent to, but should be faster than:

```
P = np.identity(4, dtype = arrs[0].dtype)
for arr in arrs:
    P = np.dot(P, arr)
```

Timing test:

```
In [52]: def byloop(arrs):
   ....:     P = np.identity(4)
   ....:     for arr in arrs:
   ....:         P = np.dot(P, arr)
   ....:     return P
   ....: 

In [53]: def byreduce(arrs):
   ....:     return reduce(np.dot, arrs)
   ....: 

In [54]: byloop(arrs)
Out[54]: 
array([[  5104,   5460,   5816,   6172],
       [ 15728,  16820,  17912,  19004],
       [ 26352,  28180,  30008,  31836],
       [ 36976,  39540,  42104,  44668]])

In [55]: byreduce(arrs)
Out[55]: 
array([[ 5104,  5460,  5816,  6172],
       [15728, 16820, 17912, 19004],
       [26352, 28180, 30008, 31836],
       [36976, 39540, 42104, 44668]])
```

where `len(arrs) = 1000`:

```
In [56]: timeit byloop(arrs)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop

In [57]: timeit byreduce(arrs)
1000 loops, best of 3: 656 us per loop
```

Comment: byloop does 3, byreduce 2 dot products. It may be faster, but its not nearly as much as your timings make it look. Also the types are not the same and identity takes unnecessary time (and with arrs being length three, those times add up a lot).

Comment: Thanks @seberg Timing with longer lists posted now.

Comment: Still the dtype issue (and that is not small), but considering that there is not much else in pure python to suggest...

Comment: @seberg The dtype mismatch comes simply from the default `np.identity` returning a float.  EDIT: fixed it in the post.

Comment: @seberg hm, I see. Do you think that's true still with the current implementation where `np.identity` takes `dtype = arrs[0].dtype`?

Comment: No, sorry, then that does not matter much. I only saw the version further down and thought you did not redo the timings too.

Answer (score 1):

For matrices this small, it might be advantageous to avoid using BLAS altogether. There are small matrix multiplication libraries out there, for example [libSMM](http://www.hector.ac.uk/cse/distributedcse/reports/cp2k03/cp2k03/node9.html) (there are more).

It might be doable to wrap them with f2py or cython, or --- it might be easier to roll your own, in cython or fortran/f2py.